# Two network cards - block port on one of them

Tags: networking, server, iptables, docker

I have two NICs **eno1** (ip: 12.34.56.78) and **eno2** (44.55.66.77).

I also have a service on a specific port (lets say **8888**) running.

I want to allow traffic over **eno1** to that service, but want to drop any packet to that port over **eno2**.

I tried it with the following `iptables` rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eno2 -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DROP
```

Also with this (some of my rules have this strange **garbage** keyword in it):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eno2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j garbage
```

But still the service is available over both NICs and their corresponding ips.

Please enlighten me about this.

The service is running as a **docker container**.

---

---

---

EDITs for comments:

`iptables -S` contains:

```
-P INPUT DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

1st Approach: specify the destination ip address

```
Iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8888 -d 44.55.66.77 -j DROP
```

2nd Approach: blocking all trafic except that one designated to ip address from 1st NIC

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 12.34.56.78 -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DROP
```

Explanation: As long as the traffic is designated to that particular ip addres, doesn't matter what is the interface from which is comming from.